# En formulario de contacto en PHP aparece la dirección del SMTP en el remitente

Tags: php

cuando me llega un correo del formulario de contacto si llega con la dirección del mail ingresado en el formulario, solo que tengo un pequeño inconveniente. Seguido del mail aparece la terminación de mi proveedor de SMTP, alguien podrá decirme porque sucede esto ?

El código es el siguiente:

```
    <?php 

require 'vistas/mail.view.php';

    define("correo", "soporte1@farmaciassanasana.com.mx");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $de=filter_var($_POST['de'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $nombre=filter_var($_POST['nombre'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $asunto=filter_var($_POST['asunto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $mensaje=filter_var($_POST['mensaje'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $mensaje.='
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <img src="sana.png" alt="Farmacias Sana Sana" width="42" height="42">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Farmacias Sana Sana</h1>
            <h2>Este es un mensaje de Farmacias Sana Sana</h2>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';

        // Para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera Content-type
        $cabeceras = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $cabeceras.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $cabeceras.= 'From: "'.$nombre.'" "'.$de.'"' . "\r\n" .
        #'Reply-To: "'.$de.'"' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/';

        if (mail(correo, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras)) {
            echo "Correo enviado satisfactoriamente";
        }else{
            echo "Fallo al enviar el mensaje";
        }
    }
 ?>
```

El correo me llega de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que después de "gspindolab@gmail.com" no aparezca absolutamente nada. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu formulario PHP es el que envía el mensaje, entonces el proveedor de envíos sera tu servidor SMTP y no la dirección de correo que ingresas. Es por este motivo también que el mensaje llega a bandeja de no deseados puesto que el servicio Outlook (en tu caso) detecta que el mensaje salió desde el formulario y no desde la bandeja de salida de la cuenta "gspindolab@gmail.com". Te recomiendo que uses PHPMailer, tiene muchas opciones de configuración y es muy fácil de implementar. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer